# Separator line is not extending to right when isEditing mode true

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

My table view looks like below on editing mode, [image]

It works fine when there is no editing mode, There is simple code just enable editing mode, But in this scenario, it is expected to extend the separator to the extreme right

```
@IBAction func didTapReorderButton(_ sender: Any) {
 workflowTableView.isEditing = btn.isSelected
}
```

[image]

Comment: it's default separator?

Comment: Just some thoughts. You are not showing any code, yet the icons in your screenshots are quite different. (That may be noise to the real issue, but is needed for me to help.) Does this work in *any* version of iOS/iPadOS? I get that for some reason you labelled this [swift5] - but I've not seen this behavior in any version of iOS/iPadOS in my apps. This might be on my end though - I fully use a UITableView delegate *without* using IB in any way. But that's hard to tell with what you've posted.

Comment: @jatinfl yes its default provided by apple.

Comment: @dfd, The current codebase doesn't contain much, its a table view created in the storyboard, and created an outlet of the same, constrains are 0 from all four side, The exact problem you will see when you try to re-order the items in the table view, you might have observer the separator line is not extending till the end. It's not swift5 specific issue, I am using the default table view separator provided in the storyboard attribute inspector, I doubt there is anything to do with outlet, same problem would be there without outlet also

Comment: @Dipesh try it with custom separator.

Comment: @jatinfl , I would opt for the custom separator option but could see the iPad device preferred language setting  option has separator ended till the last, which is the implementation of apple, so felt like its possible without much effort to apples default control, added screenshot in question

Comment: yeah default one are good but i need to know it will also do same thing ?

Comment: I didnt get you @jatinfl

Comment: means custom separator also change separator inset while editing? and here custom means try to set uilable as separator with height one.

Comment: I doubt, have not tried that, but should be possible.